Trying to align multiple Column inside Row which is inside SingleChildScrollView
Read the commented line to understand my problem
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DemoTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const DemoTest({super.key});

  @override
  State<DemoTest> createState() => _DemoTestState();
}

class _DemoTestState extends State<DemoTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          //this column sshould  start from top
          Column(
              children: List.generate(300, (index) {
            return Text(index.toString());
          })),
          //this column sshould  start from bottom

          Column(
              children: List.generate(100, (index) {
            return Text(index.toString());
          })),
          //this column again should be start from top
          Column(
              // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: List.generate(100, (index) {
            return Text(index.toString());
          }))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
what   expecting is like:
Column 1        Column 2       Column 3
0                               0
1                               1
2                               2
3                               3
4                               .
5                               .
.
.
100                0            99
.                  1
.                  .
.                  .
299                99


SingleChildScrollview -> Row -> 3 COLUMNS (Every column has diffrent alignment). Align is not working, cant add expanded because of singleChildScrollView.
Hope i able to explain every thing

Please share the image you would like to create.

what i expected is mentioned.

You can try this
class _DemoTestState extends State<DemoTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Column(
                children: List.generate(300, (index) {
                  return Text(index.toString());
                })),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: List.generate(100, (index) {
                  return Text(index.toString());
                })),
            Column(
                children: List.generate(100, (index) {
                  return Text(index.toString());
                }))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

To give some explanation. By wrapping the Row in an IntrinsicHeight it makes it that all the Row's children will get the height of the heighest child instead of the children becoming as small as possible. This way, putting a mainAxisAlignment to end to the second column will get the desired result.

Is it possible without Intrinsic Widget  because Flutter doesn't recommend to use.

I don't know if there's another way. It's true that it's a relative expensive to use IntrinsicHeight, since it makes it calculate the layout of the row's children twice, but I would say that it's not really noticeable, but it maybe also depends on the complexity of the layout. No idea how else to do it
